# Does ply.lex parse the same token once?

Tags: python, parsing, lexical-analysis, ply, lexical

I was reading a [lexical parsing](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) document so that I can parse some arguments and I exactly followed the document to create a parser. This is the whole code:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ply.lex as lex

args = ['[watashi]', '[anata]>500', '[kare]>400&&[kare]<800']

tokens = ('NUMBER', 'EXPRESSION', 'AND', 'LESS', 'MORE')

t_EXPRESSION = r'\[.*\]'
t_AND = r'&&'
t_LESS = r'<'
t_MORE = r'>'
t_ignore = '\t'

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

def t_error(t):
    print 'Illegal character "%s"' % t.value[0]
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()

for i in args:
    lexer.input(i)
    while True:
        tok = lexer.token()
        if not tok: break
        print tok
    print '#############'
```

I simply created a list of sample arguments and I got this output:

```
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[watashi]',1,0)
#############
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[anata]',1,0)
LexToken(MORE,'>',1,7)
LexToken(NUMBER,500,1,8)
#############
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[kare]>400&&[kare]',1,0)
LexToken(LESS,'<',1,18)
LexToken(NUMBER,800,1,19)
#############
```

The first and second sample arguments are parsed correctly, but the third one is not. The third sample argument is EXPRESSION+LESS+NUMBER whereas it must be EXPRESSION+MORE+NUMBER+AND+EXPRESSION+LESS+NUMBER. So I thought there could be one of those problems:

- **ply.lex is only parsing one token:** In the codes above, ply.lex cannot parse two seperate expressions and it returns the latest token as its type. "[kare]>400&&[kare]" is EXPRESSION because it ends with the latest EXPRESSION token which is second [kare] and 800 is NUMBER because it is the latest NUMBER token.

  **!!! OR !!!**
- **There is a mistake in t_EXPRESSION variable:** I defined this variable as "[.*]" to get all characters in those two brackets ([]). The first token of third sample argument is "[kare]>400&&[kare]" since it simply starts and ends with those brackets and contains .* (every single character) in them, but I thought the interpreter would stop in the first (]) character due to being first.

So I could not find  a way to solve but asked here.

in general this is what I am struggling with

```
lexer.input("[kare]>400&&[kare]<800")
while True:
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok: break
    print tok
```

I get

```
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[kare]>400&&[kare]',1,0)
LexToken(LESS,'<',1,18)
LexToken(NUMBER,800,1,19)
```

but I expected something more like

```
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[kare]',1.0)
LexToken(LESS,'>',?)
LexToken(NUMBER,400,?)
LexToken(AND,'&&',?)
LexToken(EXPRESSION,'[kare]',1,0)
LexToken(LESS,'<',1,18)
LexToken(NUMBER,800,1,19)
```

Comment: Hint: Since the lexmes are regular expressions, you can take ply out of the equation and see if your regular expression matches what you think it should match.

Comment: what is your exact input that you put in and what is the output that you get, why is the output  wrong, and what you expect... I can kind of see that you put most of these but please use code block to show the example that is wrong , put a comment next to the part of the output that is wrong, and put what you expect... it will be much easier to get an answer that way  (and put all of that in one small codeblock at the bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see your problem

```
t_EXPRESSION = r'\[.*\]'
```

is greedy and will match the biggest match it can ie `'[kare]>400&&[kare]'`

instead try

```
t_EXPRESSION = r'\[[^\]]*\]'
```

this will match only one set since it looks for not open bracket(`[^\]]`) instead of anything(`.`)

you can also use not greedy matching

```
t_EXPRESSION = r'\[.*?\]'
```

the `?` makes it match as few characters as possible rather than the maximum

Comment: '\[[^\]]\*\\]' and the other one worked well, thank you so much. :)